# trying to pass values to the mvc controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I was trying to pass values from view to controller in mvc using jquery. When I click the button `#btncontinue`, the ajax error callback is activated. I don't know why this happened. Here is the part of my code that is causing this:

```
    $("#btncontinue").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var custname = "johnson ben";
        var phone = "444-556-667";
        var email = "admin@gmail.com";


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("BookingDetails", "Room")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { phone: phone, custname: custname, email: email },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                   alart(data);
                      }, 
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error occured!!");
                    }
            });

    });
```

controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult BookingDetails(string phone, string custname, string email)
    {
         string data = phone;
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I would assume you need to remove the `contentType` option and let it send in form encoded data.

Comment: Though that is assuming that the error is with the passing in of the data.  Checking the request in your network console, why is it actually failing?  Make sure it is passing the correct information, and make note of the response and the response code